# Weight Standardization -- Using tf.keras.layers.Wrapper to update weights removes it from the list of layer.weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

**Task**

- I am trying to implement [Weight Standardization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10520) in Tensorflow 2.4.
- The goal here is to standardize the weights to mean=0, variance=1, *BEFORE* using them for convolution.

**Methods tried**

1. I have tried two methods

- [Subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) by inheriting `tf.keras.layers.Conv3D`
- [tf.keras.layers.Wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Wrapper) by following the example of [Weight Normalization from the tensorflow_addons package](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.12.0/tensorflow_addons/layers/wrappers.py#L23-L227)

**Code**

1. Subclassing

```
class Conv3DWS(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D):
    """
    Ref
     - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D
     - https://github.com/joe-siyuan-qiao/WeightStandardization
    """

    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='same'
                    , dilation_rate=(1,1,1)
                    , activation='relu'
                    , kernel_regularizer=None
                    , name=''):
        super(Conv3DWS, self).__init__(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding
                        , dilation_rate=dilation_rate
                        , activation=activation
                        , kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                        , name=name)
        print (' ------------------------------- ')
        print ('            Conv3DWS             ')
        print (' ------------------------------- ')
   
    def call(self, inputs):

        # Step 1 - WS
        kernel_mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(self.kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True, name='kernel_mean')
        kernel_std  = tf.math.reduce_std(self.kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True, name='kernel_std')
        self.kernel = (self.kernel - kernel_mean)/(kernel_std + tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
        
        # Step 2 - Just copy/paste code from tf.keras.layers.Conv 
        from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
        from tensorflow.python.ops import nn_ops
        if self._is_causal:  # Apply causal padding to inputs for Conv1D.
            inputs = array_ops.pad(inputs, self._compute_causal_padding(inputs))

        outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)

        if self.use_bias:
            output_rank = outputs.shape.rank
            if self.rank == 1 and self._channels_first:
                # nn.bias_add does not accept a 1D input tensor.
                bias = array_ops.reshape(self.bias, (1, self.filters, 1))
                outputs += bias
            else:
                # Handle multiple batch dimensions.
                if output_rank is not None and output_rank > 2 + self.rank:

                    def _apply_fn(o):
                        return tf.nn.bias_add(o, self.bias, data_format=self._tf_data_format)

                    outputs = nn_ops.squeeze_batch_dims(
                        outputs, _apply_fn, inner_rank=self.rank + 1)
                else:
                    outputs = tf.nn.bias_add(
                        outputs, self.bias, data_format=self._tf_data_format)

        if self.activation is not None:
            return self.activation(outputs)
        return outputs


x = tf.random.normal((1,140,140,40,1))
layers = Conv3DWS(filters=10, dilation_rate=(3,3,3))
y = layers(x)
print (' - [Conv3DWS] y: ', y.shape)
if len(layers.weights) >= 2: # layer.trainable_variables
    kernel = layers.weights[0]
    tf.print(' - [Conv3DWS][tf.nn.conv3d] kernel_mean: ', tf.math.reduce_mean(kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True))
    tf.print(' - [Conv3DWS][tf.nn.conv3d] kernel_std : ', tf.math.reduce_std(kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True))
else:
    tf.print(' - Only one weight present')
```

2. Wrapper

```
class WeightStandardization(tf.keras.layers.Wrapper):
    """
    Ref
     - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Wrapper
     - https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.12.0/tensorflow_addons/layers/wrappers.py#L23-L227
     - https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=NervanaSystems%2Fnlp-architect%2Fnlp-architect-master%2Fnlp_architect%2Fmodels%2Ftemporal_convolutional_network.py
    """
    
    def __init__(self, layer: tf.keras.layers, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Layer):
            raise ValueError('Please initialize `WeightStandardization` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. You passed: {input}'.format(input=layer))
        super(WeightStandardization, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)
        
        self.initialized = True

    def build(self, input_shape=None):
        if not self.layer.built:
            self.layer.build(input_shape)
        self.built = True

    def call(self, x):

        with tf.name_scope("compute_weights"):
            
            kernel_mean       = tf.math.reduce_mean(self.layer.kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True, name='kernel_mean')
            kernel_std        = tf.math.reduce_std(self.layer.kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True, name='kernel_std')
            self.layer.kernel = (self.layer.kernel - kernel_mean)/(kernel_std + tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
            update_kernel     = tf.identity(self.layer.kernel)

            # Ensure we calculate result after updating kernel.
            with tf.control_dependencies([update_kernel]):    
                outputs = self.layer(x)
                return outputs

x = tf.random.normal((1,140,140,40,1))
layers = WeightStandardization(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=10, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=(1,1,1), padding='SAME', dilation_rate=(3,3,1), name='ConvWS'))
y = layers(x)
print (' - [Conv3DWS] y: ', y.shape)
if len(layers.weights) >= 2: # layer.trainable_variables
    kernel = layers.weights[0]
    tf.print(' - kernel_mean: ', tf.math.reduce_mean(kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True))
    tf.print(' - kernel_std : ', tf.math.reduce_std(kernel, axis=[0,1,2,3], keepdims=True))
else:
    tf.print(' - Only one weight present')
```

**Problem**

- In both the cases when I pass an input through the layer, and then check for the trainable weights, I only see the bias and the kernel disappears. So what have I gotten wrong here? Is it the build() method?